# How to create bitmap font texture in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, truetype, text-rendering

So I was trying to learn OpenGL from [learnopengl.com](http://learnopengl.com) and I'm currently on the topic of text rendering and I thought about combining scalable font textures in my program to one big texture, but for some reason, I get an exception bc of `glCopyImageSubData(...).`

First I try to measure how big the texture should be and then copy textures I already created to one big texture, and I was playing with this function for quite a while now but I can't find a solution.

Here is the [original code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=in-practice/text_rendering) with texture used for each face.

I tried to create `fbo` and attach a texture to it, but after research, I found this function that was far more clear to me so I decided to use it instead.

So I added `xoffset` to Character structure:

```
struct Character {
    GLuint      textureID;
    glm::ivec2  size;
    glm::ivec2  bearing;
    GLuint      advance;
    GLuint      xoffset;
};
```

I add this offset to each face in the first for loop:

```
    Character character = {
                texture,
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows),
                glm::ivec2(face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top),
                face->glyph->advance.x,
                font_texture_width
            };
            font_texture_width += character.size.x;
            characters.insert(std::pair<GLchar, Character>(c, character));
```

And then I try to paste each face texture to fontTexture:

```
glGenTextures(1, &fontTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED,
font_texture_width, 100, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    std::cout << glGetError();
    for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; ++c)
        glCopyImageSubData( characters[c].textureID, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            fontTexture, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, characters[c].xoffset, 0, 0,
                            characters[c].size.x, characters[c].size.y, 0);
```

Here is modyfied renderText function:

```
void renderText(Shader &s, std::string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, glm::vec3 color)
{
    s.use();
    s.setVec3("textColor", color);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    std::string::const_iterator c;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
    for (c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); ++c)
    {
        Character ch = characters[*c];
        GLfloat xpos = x + ch.bearing.x * scale;
        GLfloat ypos = y - (ch.size.y - ch.bearing.y) * scale;
        GLfloat w = ch.size.x * scale;
        GLfloat h = ch.size.y * scale;
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { xpos + characters[*c].xoffset,        ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos + characters[*c].xoffset,        ypos,       0.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w + characters[*c].xoffset,    ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + characters[*c].xoffset,        ypos + h,   0.0, 0.0 },
            { xpos + w + characters[*c].xoffset,    ypos,       1.0, 1.0 },
            { xpos + w + characters[*c].xoffset,    ypos + h,   1.0, 0.0 }
        };
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        x += (ch.advance >> 6) * scale;
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Exception is being thrown where I call *glCopyImageSubData*.

Here is my whole program: https://pastebin.com/vAeeX3Xh

EDIT:

Now I figured out that it would be better to use *glTexSubImage2D* instead, so this is how it looks like (instead of this block of code with *glCopyImageSubData*)

```
glGenTextures(1, &fontTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontTexture);
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RED,
    face->glyph->bitmap.width * 250,
    face->glyph->bitmap.rows * 250,
    0,
    GL_RED,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    NULL
);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; ++c)
{
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load Glyph" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, characters[c].xoffset, 0, characters[c].size.x, characters[c].size.y, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
}
```

Now when I render this texture it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nU9Iu.jpg

Comment: glCopyImageSubData was largely a broken function on AMD64 platform. Also got some issues with textures if they stored in compressed form. What kind of exception you have, you never posted the actual error message.

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in FreeTypePack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

I'm using acer swift 3 laptop with intel hd620 on board

Comment: Do you even _have_ the `glCopyImageSubData` function?

Comment: it doesn't look like function was loaded\available. your function pointer is 0

Comment: I checked my opengl version and it is 4.4 but now It doesn't matter bc I changed my code now pls Check my edit